# Integration of matlab dll in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, matlab, dll

I'm writing here because I have a problem that I cannot solve by myself...

I developed Matlab functions that I wanted to transfer to VB.Net through a .dll. I successfully compiled the .dll with Matlab compiler and imported it to VB.NET.

But now I'm trying to use it and i definitely don't understand why it doesn't work. That is what I wrote on VB.net

```
Imports StatFeaturesExtractor
sub*****
        Dim Extractor As StatFeaturesExtractor.Extractor
        Dim MatlabTypePath As MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Arrays.MWArray
        MatlabTypePath = New MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Arrays.MWCharArray(path)  '==> this line already bug...
        Dim Result As MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Arrays.MWArray
        Result = Extractor.StatFeatureExtractor(MatlabTypePath)
  end sub
```

for your comprehension, `StatFeatureExtractor` is a simple to use (theoretically) as the only argument is a string (a path) and the result consist of a 8x1 array of double

thank for your help